# Meteor - rendering template with a document from a Collection

Tags: meteor

Basically, I'm just trying to render a template with the `result` attribute of a document returned by a MongoDB find() call.  I have autosubscribe on.

I have an html template

```
<template name="results">
    status: {{result}}
</template>
```

And I'm trying to render it in the js file:

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {
    Template.results.result = function() {
        return Results.find({'type': 'test'}).fetch()[0].result;
    }
}
```

There's a record in mongo `{type: "test", result: "success"}`.  The code keeps throwing an error that "undefined has no attribute result".  However, when I just return `Results.find({'type': 'test'}).fetch()[0]` it does actually return an object, not undefined (and if I log it to the console, I can see that it does have the `result` attribute I set).

The only thing I can think of is that it might be related to the reactive behavior of meteor - maybe the MongoDB call is initially returning undefined, and then later updating to contain the correct document.  Is that correct?  And if so, how can I get the value of the `result` attribute of that document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template gets rendered as soon as the client starts up, before the server has sent the documents in Results.  Try this (`findOne` is shorthand for `fetch()[0]`):

```
Template.results.result = function() {
    var obj = Results.findOne({'type' : 'test'});
    return obj && obj.result;
}
```

Comment: what if your findOne is inside of a method and the Template.this.that is calling the method.  The method is also being called by other code that is not template oriented and it errors when you return obj && obj.result?  How do you handle that case?  I am running into this and I don't want to open another thread if I don't have to.

Comment: What's the use case for this?  Templates probably shouldn't be calling methods.  Anytime the screen redraws, you'd make a roundtrip to the server.  The Meteor approach is to subscribe to the data that drives templates, so that screen draws compensate for the latency of that round trip.

Comment: Ignore, had to edit this, answered wrong.  I will try that.  But what I am trying to do is reduce duplication of code.  Template.this.that = function() { var obj = myObject.myMethodGetData(Session.get("search_value")); return obj; };  Allows other code to call myObject.myMethodGetData in order to get at that data as well.

Comment: BTW, method being called is in /client/, mabye I should open an SO on this?  The data is already subscribed to client side.

Comment: sorry for all the comments, we figured this out in IRC and the gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/2793220)