# Accessing contents of DB query

Tags: meteor

I must be missing something essential, but here is my problem. I have a Documents collection that contains 'title' and 'content' fields.

When I navigate to a particular url, say,

```
http://localhost:3000/document/33ea5676-4f8f-4fe4-99d5-fe094556933d
```

I grab the document _id from the url, store it via `Session.set('docID',_id)` and then want to, say, display the title of the document. I have a template:

```
<template name='document'>
  <h2>My document is called {{document.title}}</h2>
</template>
```

And then in my client.js file, I have:

```
Template.document.document = function() {
  doc = Documents.findOne({'_id':Session.get('docID')});
  return doc;
}
```

But this does not work: I receive an error along the lines of:

```
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

Because, of course, before the field can be accessed, the document must be retrieved from the database. If I call,

```
Template.document.document().title
```

from the console, I retrieve the title. I tried making a title specific function,

```
Template.document.title = function() {
  doc = Documents.findOne({'_id':Session.get('docID')});
  return doc.title;
}
```

But this suffers from the same problem. There seems to be a lag between when the database retrieves the entry, and in the meantime calling `doc.title` throws an error.

I must be overlooking something fundamental here. Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167464/meteor-rendering-template-with-a-document-from-a-collection  Short answer: `return doc && doc.title`

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'with' in your template:

```
Template.document.document = function() {
  return Documents.findOne({'_id':Session.get('docID')});
}

<template name='document'>
  {{#with document}}
    <h2>My document is called {{title}}</h2>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```